# How to create a correct uuid ws-discovery service with wso2 Governance and ESB (4.1)?

Tags: wsdl, registry, wso2, uuid, wso2-esb

I created few WS-Discovery services in static endpoint (URL) or dynamic endpoint (uuid) mode by wso2 Governance discovery proxy service on ESB server.

The uuid-based WS-Discovery services can not find/get WSDL message from discovery proxy, but another service does. How to setup a correct uuid ws-discovery service with Governance and ESB (4.1)? Thanks.

The ESB error log as the following:
ERROR - ProxyServiceMessageReceiver Unable to find the endpoint specified : wsdd://xxxxxx

PS. I already add the wsDiscoveryParams parameter to set the discoverable on at ESB:

```
<proxy name="EchoProxy" transports="https,http" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
    <target endpoint="wsdd://urn:uuid:a74a1bc6-3f25-4d02-bcbc-ea31a3f0f33e/https"/>
    <parameter name="wsDiscoveryParams">
        <Scopes xmlns="ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">echo.services.core.carbon.wso2.org</Scopes>
    </parameter>
</proxy>
```

Comment: the same happens to me, don't know what the problem is ...

Comment: Has someone figured out the cause of this problem? It's happening to me as well

Answer (score 0):

Try to Create Proxy Services with "http" target address instead of https, or try to create and EP with http target, first and then create a proxy service...just a suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my situation was a little different than the question's, but I was getting the same error message from the ESB 4.8.1. My solution was to download the file "org.wso2.carbon.discovery.mediation.ext_4.0.0.jar" from [here](http://product-dist.wso2.com/p2/carbon/releases/4.0.2/plugins/), put it in the folder %ESB_HOME%/repository/components/dropins, and restart the ESB server.

Just as a double check, I made sure that the code lines `<parameter name="extensions">org.wso2.carbon.discovery.mediation.ext.WSDiscoveryRegistryExtension</parameter>` and `<parameter name="discoveryProxy">https://%GRegIp:port%/services/DiscoveryProxy</parameter>` were inside the "registry" tag, which is located in the ESB console->Manage->Service Bus->Soure View.